# Use Cauchy Product to Prove sum of sine squared and cosine squared is 1

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-product

I know this solution has already been shown but each time I have seen examples of this proof I get lost at the last step.

\begin{align}
\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x &= \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!}\biggl(\sum_{k = 0}^r \binom{2r}{2k}(-1)^{2k}\biggr)x^{2r} + \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!}\biggl(\sum_{k = 0}^r \binom{2r}{2k+1}(-1)^{2k+1}\biggr)x^{2r} \\
&= \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!}\biggl(\sum_{k = 0}^r \binom{2r}{2k}(-1)^{2k} + \sum_{k = 0}^{r-1}\binom{2r}{2k+1}(-1)^{2k+1}\biggr)x^{2r}\\
&= \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!}\biggl(\sum_{j = 0}^{2r} \binom{2r}{j}(-1)^j\biggr)x^{2r}.
\end{align}

What I do not understand is how the addition of the two sums in the second to last step shown result in
\begin{align}
\sum_{j = 0}^{2r} \binom{2r}{j}(-1)^j\
\end{align}

I feel like I am missing something obvious but how 2r appears in the sum is really confusing me. Thanks, I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you know that $e^{a+b}=e^{a}\cdot e^{b}$ and $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$, there is a way shorter proof: $$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=\left(\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\right) \cdot \left(\cos(z)-i\sin(z)\right)$$ $$= e^{iz}\cdot e^{-iz} = e^0 = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

That's a reasonable confusion  :)

On the middle line, the first inner sum has binomials whose lower entry is $2k$ as $k$ runs from $0$ to $r$; this set of lower entries is the same as all the even numbers between $0$ and $2r$ (inclusive). Then, the second inner sum on the middle line has binomials whose lower entry is $2k+1$ as $k$ runs from $0$ to $r-1$; this set of lower entries is the same as all the odd numbers between $1$ and $2r-1$ (inclusive). Together, they make up all possible lower entries (odd or even) between $0$ and $2r$ (inclusive); that's where the range of summation in the bottom line comes from.